# Addition from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to add this:

```
if (question_counter==10){
    $query3 = "SELECT answer_points WHERE participation_id=".$participation_id;
    $dbc->query($query3)    
}
```

This is supposed to get all the answer_points where the participation_id = "something". This happens when I receive in my PHP function that question_counter has reached 10

I now want to perform an addition between all the results I receive in my query above so that I can find out a total score and store it as a variable.

How would I go about doing this efficiently?

I thought about writing queries for each answer where I get the participation_id and the question_counter to write the query, store each row result in a separate variable and add all those together. I think this is an overkill and dumb since I will have to write 10 queries to get each row's result.

**Anyway this is my Table**
[image]

Comment: Do you want Sum of answer_points of each participants?

Comment: Do you mean something simple like `$query3 = "SELECT SUM(answer_points) answer_points FROM mytable WHERE participation_id=".$participation_id;`, or are you trying to sum per participant, or...?

Comment: You can use SUM in SQL Query, SELECT sum(answer_points) WHERE participation_id="something";

Comment: Is this PDO? If so you have no reason to be using string concatenation and making gigantic [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) when a simple placeholder would make this rock solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [SUM function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

```
SELECT SUM(columnName) AS totalScore FROM tableName WHERE id = 34;
```

Comment: Thanks, How would I go about doing that in my query?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I added an example of the SUM function in use.

Comment: Is totalScore a variable that is created that I can use?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Yes. It is an alias; allowing you to access it like so `$row['totalScore']`

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not correct.

```
 $query3 = "SELECT answer_points FROM table_name WHERE participation_id=".$participation_id;
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                 from and table name
```

You have forgot from and table name in the query.

To get the sum of the column you need to use the SUM function of mysql.

Here is tutorial of [SUM function in mysql](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write query using [SUM function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

```
 $query3 = "SELECT SUM(answer_points) AS answer_points
            FROM TABLE_NAME
            WHERE participation_id=".$participation_id;
```